# Make a work item field read only when in a state but not when transitioning to it in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I'm currently working on a custom process template to use with TFS2010. I want to impose some restrictions on my work items. I have a 'Task' work item that will start in the 'To Do' state when created.  When transitioning to the next state 'In Progress' I have it specified that the field 'Original Estimate' is required.  So far so good.

To expand on this, I want to make the field readonly when it is in the 'In Progress' state but allowing it to be editable when doing the transition.  Currently, when I set readonly for that field on the 'In Progress' state I am unable to then enter a value.  The only it would work is to enter the value in the 'To Do' state, save and then transition. I would like to avoid that interim save step if possible.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't succeed because you setting the readonly field constraint in a state and not in a transition to a state.

Put your readonly constraint in the 'in progress' state, but not in the transition(s) from 'to do' to 'in progress'.

In the process template edition right click on the transition box, then select properties (IIRC), you'll be in a familiar place.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`FROZEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194953.aspx)?

> Specifies that you cannot change the field to a non-empty value after
>   changes are committed. As soon as a user saves the work item with a
>   value in that field, the value can no longer be modified.

Comment: I've thought about FROZEN but I do want it to be changeable if it was moved back to a to do state... though I am starting to think this probably defeats the point of having it restricted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found away around what I was trying to do by using the WHENNOTCHANGEDCONDITION.

By using this on the 'In Progress' state, I set the 'Original Estimate' field to READONLY when the 'State' is not being changed.

I would've tried FROZEN as Dave suggested, but I would like it to be amendable if returned to the previous state.